# How to navigate to given coordinates in paint.net?

Tags: tools, shortcuts, paint.net

I'm using the `Rectangle Select tool` - I'm selecting an area of `300px x 300px`, starting from `0,0` coordinates. I'd like to quickly jump to coordinates `300,0`.

Is there any shortcut which I can use to achieve that? I had a look at the docs (without success).

Answer (score 1):

**I just realized this was a paint.net question, but maybe something similar to this will work there haha.**

This may not be the most effective method, but if you leave your 300 x 300 selection active, you can always drag some guides out.

[image: selection]

I dragged two, just to show you that they will snap to the bounds of your selection, but you get the idea.

[image: guides]

To drag a guide, turn on your `Rulers` (<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>) and then drag a guide from the ruler to where you would like it in your document.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately no shortcut for this without programming. You can instead try this:

Paint.NET allows some settings to the rectangular selection tool. You can easily set Selection mode = Fixed size and input the selection size = 300 x 300 pixels in the tool options panel. In reasonably high zoom it's easy to click & drag the selection exactly to the left top corner.

If you must do other rectangular selections before making the next 300x300 selection, you can simply change the selection mode to normal. When you change the selection mode again to Fixed size, there's 300x300 size waiting.

Actually there's a shortcut Shift+S for all selection tools. Press Shift+S until the rectangular selection tool is active. After it clicking with mouse is needed to place the selection.